# Why session data shows in different browsers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, ninject

I'm using ninject to inject the HttpSessionStateBase into a custom SessionData class. This Session data class sets a dictionary object on the http session that was injected in. The session data class gets injected into the controller.

As you visit pages, view model data gets appended into this dictionary. If you do this in Chrome and then open up the site in FireFox, all form data will be filled in. How is this happening. Any suggestions as to what to look for?

Here is the ninject bindings:

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        kernel.Bind<HttpRequestBase>().ToMethod(b => b.Kernel.Get<HttpContextBase>().Request)
            .InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<HttpResponseBase>().ToMethod(b => b.Kernel.Get<HttpContextBase>().Response)
            .InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<HttpServerUtilityBase>().ToMethod(b => b.Kernel.Get<HttpContextBase>().Server)
            .InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<HttpSessionStateBase>().ToMethod(b => b.Kernel.Get<HttpContextBase>().Session)
            .InRequestScope();

        kernel.Bind<ISessionData>().To<SessionData>().InRequestScope();

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        return kernel;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the bindings please? Looks like a scope issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. See code above.

Comment: It was not ninject or my custom session data class. What I am doing is saving a singleton in the session which is fine. The singleton was returning the data from a static property which in return was NOT getting/setting the data using HttpContext.Current.Session. I still don't like the use of the singleton (it was there when I started the project) but static properties can be very evil.